# magento 2 - multistore - single invoice system

Tags: magento2, multistore, invoice, sales-invoice

I've just setup a working multistore website.

If someone orders an item from the **us-version of the website**, `#0000001` will be designated as the invoice number.

But if someone else orders something from the **spanish site**, `#2000001` will be designated.

How can I change this so that the all new orders will be `#0000002, #0000003,` etc `instead of #2000001`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest taking a look at the `sale_sequence_profile` table.

See here for more details

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/complete-tutorial-guide-change-order-number-magento-2/

But essentially you are modifying suffix/prefix in addition to what's already generated.

So the answer is it can't be done.  That's how magento works.